# Mercurial replication

Tags: mercurial, replication

I'm trying to configure replication Mercurial hg server

I have a repository test1 and a subrepository test2

On the second server I run command

`hg clone --noupdate https://user:password@sserver1/test1`

`hg clone --noupdate https://user:password@sserver1/test2`

then `hg pull`

Download successful

Futher I clone repository on clint PC

```
hg clone https://user:password@sserver2/test1
```

and I get error authorization failed (in subrepository «test2»)
If open file .hgsub

```
test2 = https://server1/test2
```

instead, there should be

```
test2 = https://server2/test2
```

that is, the sub-repository error refers to the first server and should refer to the second

How do right setting replicatiom Mercurial hg?

Comment: 1. If you want to have path in .hgsub reflected changes of location, you **must** to define and use relative path - absolute paths aren't changed after any clone 2. Two unrelated clones are, in common, **The Bad Idea (tm)** (AFAICR)

Comment: "The right-hand side is a either a path relative to the place you clone from, or an absolute path. If it is a relative path then if you do hg clone mainrepo my-main then Mercurial will create a new repository at my-main/where/to/put/the/subrepo and will fill it with changesets taken from mainrepo/where/to/get/the/subrepo. If it is an absolute path it will naturally take the changesets from where/to/get/the/subrepo""- http://mercurial.aragost.com/kick-start/en/subrepositories/

Comment: Or you can play with https://www.selenic.com/mercurial/hgrc.5.html#subpaths